# Is it possible to access the vocabulary list from the nltk vectorizer in an NLP ML pipeline?

Tags: nlp, nltk, data-science, pipeline

My pipeline looks like

```
model = make_pipeline(
    TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, min_df=5),
    MultiOutputClassifier(
        estimator=AdaBoostClassifier(
            base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2),
            n_estimators=10, learning_rate=1)))
```

I want to get the dictionary assembled by `TfidfVectorizer`.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have fit your `model` the `vocabulary_` parameter appears.  You can access it with

```
model['tfidfvectorizer'].vocabulary_
```

which returns a dictionary containing all the tokens and their counts.